# Pinescript : How to know if close is greater than at least 2 ema among 6 ema

Tags: pine-script

Can you help me to know how to define a certain condition:
The price (close) must be at least above 2 emas among 6 emas.
I'm talking about emas but it can also be pivot points, SSA/SSB of ichimoku clouds...

THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a counter for that.

```
ema_val1 = ...
ema_val2 = ...
ema_val3 = ...
ema_val4 = ...
ema_val5 = ...
ema_val6 = ...

cnt = 0

cnt := (close > ema_val1) ? cnt + 1 : cnt  // Increase the counter if the close is greater than the ema value, keep it the same otherwise
cnt := (close > ema_val2) ? cnt + 1 : cnt
cnt := (close > ema_val3) ? cnt + 1 : cnt
cnt := (close > ema_val4) ? cnt + 1 : cnt
cnt := (close > ema_val5) ? cnt + 1 : cnt
cnt := (close > ema_val6) ? cnt + 1 : cnt

// Use cnt as you wish
```

Comment: Oh ok yes it's a good method thank you very much!